# Nanoframework Couldn't find a valid native assembly

Tags: esp32, nanoframework

I have ESP32_WROOM_32 with VisualStudio.
Before build and flash in VS2019, I flashed target with `nanoff --update --target ESP32_WROOM_32 --serialport COM5`
When I use nuget, to install Gpio, Wifi, Mqtt... etc, i see, that there is unrecommended versions of this libraries. ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gakWt.png))
OK, I thought. Lets download this chain:

- nanoFramework.CoreLibrary 1.11.7
- nanoFramework.System.Device.Gpio 1.0.2

Press FLASH... Error:

```
17:23:31.965 [Starting deployment transaction from v2019.10.0+69f6b0d48e]
17:23:31.971 [Starting debug engine on nanoDevice]
17:23:32.032 [Connecting to debug engine...OK]
17:23:32.436 [Couldn't find a valid native assembly required by mscorlib v1.11.7.2, checksum 0xC5322585]
17:23:32.436 [The connected target does not have support for mscorlib.]
```

I note, that if i use

- nanoFramework.CoreLibrary 1.10.5
- nanoFramework.System.Device.Gpio 1.0.1

everything works fine.

> **I understand** that the problem is that the mscorlib version in the target (ESP32) = 1.10.5.4 and it is not possible to use the nanoFramework.CoreLibrary 1.11.7 or 1.12.x

MAIN QUESTION: How can I upgrade the version in my ESP, to use latest libraries?

**Device details**

```
System Information
HAL build info: nanoFramework running @ ESP32
  Target:   ESP32_WROOM_32
  Platform: ESP32

Firmware build Info:
  Date:        Aug 25 2021
  Type:        MinSizeRel build with IDF v3.3.5
  CLR Version: 1.7.0.618
  Compiler:    GNU ARM GCC v5.2.0

OEM Product codes (vendor, model, SKU): 0, 0, 0

Serial Numbers (module, system):
  00000000000000000000000000000000
  0000000000000000

Target capabilities:
  Has nanoBooter: NO
  IFU capable: NO
  Has proprietary bootloader: YES

AppDomains:

Assemblies:
  Esp32_Test, 1.0.0.0
  nanoFramework.Runtime.Events, 1.9.1.3
  System.Device.Gpio, 1.0.1.2
  mscorlib, 1.10.5.4

Native Assemblies:
  mscorlib v100.5.0.12, checksum 0x132BDB6F
  nanoFramework.Runtime.Native v100.0.8.0, checksum 0x2307A8F3
  nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32 v100.0.7.2, checksum 0x1B75B894
  nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32.Rmt v100.0.3.0, checksum 0x9A53BB44
  nanoFramework.Devices.OneWire v100.0.3.4, checksum 0xA5C172BD
  nanoFramework.Networking.Sntp v100.0.4.4, checksum 0xE2D9BDED
  nanoFramework.ResourceManager v100.0.0.1, checksum 0xDCD7DF4D
  nanoFramework.System.Collections v100.0.0.1, checksum 0x5A31313D
  nanoFramework.System.Text v100.0.0.1, checksum 0x8E6EB73D
  nanoFramework.Runtime.Events v100.0.8.0, checksum 0x0EAB00C9
  EventSink v1.0.0.0, checksum 0xF32F4C3E
  System.IO.FileSystem v1.0.0.0, checksum 0x3112D24C
  System.Math v100.0.5.2, checksum 0xC9E0AB13
  System.Net v100.1.3.4, checksum 0xC74796C2
  Windows.Devices.Adc v100.1.3.3, checksum 0xCA03579A
  System.Device.Dac v100.0.0.6, checksum 0x02B3E860
  System.Device.Gpio v100.1.0.4, checksum 0xB6D0ACC1
  Windows.Devices.Gpio v100.1.2.2, checksum 0xC41539BE
  Windows.Devices.I2c v100.2.0.2, checksum 0x79EDBF71
  System.Device.I2c v100.0.0.1, checksum 0xFA806D33
  Windows.Devices.Pwm v100.1.3.3, checksum 0xBA2E2251
  Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication v100.1.1.2, checksum 0x34BAF06E
  System.IO.Ports v100.1.1.3, checksum 0x61B8380C
  Windows.Devices.Spi v100.1.4.2, checksum 0x360239F1
  System.Device.Spi v100.1.0.0, checksum 0x48031DC5
  Windows.Devices.Wifi v100.0.6.2, checksum 0xA94A849E
  Windows.Storage v100.0.2.0, checksum 0x954A4192
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using another firmware image. That one it's outdated. Please check the available target names in our Home repo. Or just use nanoff with --platform esp32 instead of --target Name. That will choose the appropriate firmware according to the connected device capabilities.

Comment: Yes you are right! I just opn cmd and update target with `nanoff --update --platform esp32 --serialport COM5 --preview`
Thank you! Now I can update core library to 1.12.0.preview9

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem, emphasis on using nanoff --platform instead of old --target